# MS Access 2007 end user access

Tags: microsoft-access, sharepoint

I need some good advise.  I have used Access for many years and I use Sharepoint but never the two combined.  My newly created Access db needs to be shared with many users across the organization. The back end is SQL and the old way to distribute the database would be placing the db on a shared drive, connecting their PC ODBC connections to the SQL db and then they would open the database and have at it.  This has become the OLD way.  What is the best (and simpliest) way to allow the end users to utilize a frontend for data entry/edit reporting etc.  Can I create a link through SharePoint and the user just open it from there.

Your good advise is greatly approciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way, for many years, has been to give each user their own copy of the Access front end database file.   And not to share the file among multiple users as this can lead to corruption of the front end file.  See the [Splitting your app into a front end and back end Tips](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/splitapp/) page for more info.    My no longer free [Auto FE Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/) utility can be used to distribute the Access FE.   There are alternative methods mentioned of the bottom of the FAQ page.

Access 2010 now has a web version utilizing SharePoint but it uses data macros.  SharePoint is used to store the data as well as the web database file for distribution.

Comment: Great explaination, I'm going to look into upgrading 2010.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint by design will not permit the Access DB to be uploaded.  In addition, trying to open it in teh SP site will present issues as it may try and create lock files and such.